# HD6870 segmentation fault with fglrx

Tags: 10.10, xorg, ati, fglrx

Installing a new system.

- Intel Core i7 870 Socket 1156 2.93Ghz Tray
- Gigabyte GA-P55A-UD3 P55 CHIPSET
- 8GB Transcend DDR3 1333Mhz (4 x 2GB)
- Sapphire ATI Radeon 6870 1GB GDDR5
- Ubuntu 10.10 64bit

After installing the proprietary fglrx display adapter driver using the "Additional Drivers" wizard and rebooting the system I'm getting the following segmentation fault in Xorg log. The system hangs.

To get the system back into operational state I had to use feed grub with the "single"  parameter, to force ubuntu into recovery mode, which in turn allowed me to boot in fail safe graphical mode...

```
maxim@bolt:~$ cat /var/log/Xorg.99.log 
[    49.448] 
X.Org X Server 1.9.0
Release Date: 2010-08-20
[    49.448] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    49.448] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-27-server x86_64 Ubuntu
[    49.448] Current Operating System: Linux bolt 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:32:27 UTC 2010 x86_64
[    49.448] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic root=UUID=948c9620-0ef2-4807-8e8d-edb26751723c ro quiet splash single
[    49.448] Build Date: 16 September 2010  06:18:41PM
[    49.448] xorg-server 2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    49.448] Current version of pixman: 0.18.4
[    49.448]     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    49.448] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    49.448] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.99.log", Time: Mon Nov  8 01:44:58 2010
[    49.448] (II) Loader magic: 0x7d0200
[    49.448] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    49.448]     X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    49.448]     X.Org Video Driver: 8.0
[    49.448]     X.Org XInput driver : 11.0
[    49.448]     X.Org Server Extension : 4.0
[    49.449] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1002:6738:1002:00d0 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xfbcc0000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000ce00/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    49.449] List of video drivers:
[    49.449]     apm
[    49.449]     neomagic
[    49.449]     openchrome
[    49.449]     s3virge
[    49.449]     r128
[    49.449]     vmwlegacy
[    49.449]     nouveau
[    49.449]     cirrus
[    49.449]     ark
[    49.449]     radeon
[    49.449]     tseng
[    49.449]     savage
[    49.449]     rendition
[    49.449]     chips
[    49.450]     voodoo
[    49.450]     mga
[    49.450]     trident
[    49.450]     nv
[    49.450]     intel
[    49.450]     i128
[    49.450]     siliconmotion
[    49.450]     mach64
[    49.450]     vmware
[    49.450]     ati
[    49.450]     sis
[    49.450]     sisusb
[    49.450]     fglrx
[    49.450]     s3
[    49.450]     tdfx
[    49.450]     fbdev
[    49.450]     vesa
[    49.450] (II) LoadModule: "apm"
[    49.450] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/apm_drv.so
[    49.455] (II) Module apm: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.455]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.2.3
[    49.455]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.455]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.456] (II) LoadModule: "neomagic"
[    49.456] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/neomagic_drv.so
[    49.466] (II) Module neomagic: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.466]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.2.4
[    49.466]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.466]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.466] (II) LoadModule: "openchrome"
[    49.466] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
[    49.474] (II) Module openchrome: vendor="http://openchrome.org/"
[    49.474]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.2.904
[    49.474]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.474]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.474] (II) LoadModule: "s3virge"
[    49.474] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/s3virge_drv.so
[    49.493] (II) Module s3virge: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.493]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.10.4
[    49.493]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.493]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.493] (II) LoadModule: "r128"
[    49.493] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so
[    49.495] (II) Module r128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.495]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 6.8.1
[    49.495]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.495]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.495] (II) LoadModule: "vmwlegacy"
[    49.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmwlegacy_drv.so
[    49.505] (II) Module vmwlegacy: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.505]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 11.0.1
[    49.505]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.505]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.505] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    49.505] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    49.506] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.506]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.0.16
[    49.506]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.506]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.506] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus"
[    49.506] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_drv.so
[    49.507] (II) Module cirrus: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.507]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.3.2
[    49.507]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.507]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.507] (II) LoadModule: "ark"
[    49.507] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ark_drv.so
[    49.508] (II) Module ark: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.508]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.7.2
[    49.508]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.508]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.508] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    49.508] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    49.511] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.511]     compiled for 1.9.0, module version = 6.13.1
[    49.511]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.511]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.512] (II) LoadModule: "tseng"
[    49.512] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/tseng_drv.so
[    49.521] (II) Module tseng: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.521]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.1.0
[    49.521]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.521]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.521] (II) LoadModule: "savage"
[    49.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/savage_drv.so
[    49.522] (II) Module savage: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.522]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 2.3.1
[    49.522]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.522]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.522] (II) LoadModule: "rendition"
[    49.522] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/rendition_drv.so
[    49.523] (II) Module rendition: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.523]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 4.2.4
[    49.523]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.523]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.523] (II) LoadModule: "chips"
[    49.523] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/chips_drv.so
[    49.524] (II) Module chips: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.524]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.2.3
[    49.524]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.524]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.524] (II) LoadModule: "voodoo"
[    49.524] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/voodoo_drv.so
[    49.525] (II) Module voodoo: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.525]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.1.0
[    49.525]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.525]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.525] (II) LoadModule: "mga"
[    49.525] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mga_drv.so
[    49.526] (II) Module mga: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.526]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.4.11
[    49.526]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.526]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.526] (II) LoadModule: "trident"
[    49.526] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/trident_drv.so
[    49.527] (II) Module trident: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.527]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.3.4
[    49.527]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.527]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.527] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    49.527] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nv_drv.so
[    49.528] (II) Module nv: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.528]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 2.1.17
[    49.528]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.528]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.528] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    49.529] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    49.530] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.530]     compiled for 1.9.0, module version = 2.12.0
[    49.530]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.530]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.530] (II) LoadModule: "i128"
[    49.530] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/i128_drv.so
[    49.531] (II) Module i128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.531]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.3.3
[    49.531]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.531]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.531] (II) LoadModule: "siliconmotion"
[    49.531] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/siliconmotion_drv.so
[    49.532] (II) Module siliconmotion: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.532]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.7.4
[    49.532]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.532]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.532] (II) LoadModule: "mach64"
[    49.533] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mach64_drv.so
[    49.534] (II) Module mach64: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.534]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 6.8.2
[    49.534]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.534]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.534] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
[    49.534] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
[    49.535] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.535]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 11.0.1
[    49.535]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.535]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.535] (II) LoadModule: "vmwgfx"
[    49.535] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vmwgfx
[    49.535] (II) UnloadModule: "vmwgfx"
[    49.535] (EE) Failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0)
[    49.535] (EE) vmware: Please ignore the above warnings about not being able to to load module/driver vmwgfx
[    49.535] (II) vmware: Using vmwlegacy driver everything is fine.
[    49.535] (II) LoadModule: "vmwlegacy"
[    49.535] (II) Reloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmwlegacy_drv.so
[    49.535] (II) UnloadModule: "vmwlegacy"
[    49.535] (II) Failed to load module "vmwlegacy" (already loaded, 8232992)
[    49.535] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    49.535] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    49.535] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.535]     compiled for 1.9.0, module version = 6.13.1
[    49.535]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.535]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.535] (II) LoadModule: "sis"
[    49.536] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.so
[    49.538] (II) Module sis: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.538]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.10.3
[    49.538]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.538]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.538] (II) LoadModule: "sisusb"
[    49.538] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sisusb_drv.so
[    49.539] (II) Module sisusb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.539]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.9.4
[    49.539]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.539]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.539] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    49.539] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    49.680] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
[    49.691]     compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 8.78.30
[    49.691]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.701] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    49.701] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    49.701] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrxdrm
[    49.701] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    49.701] (EE) Can't load FireGL DRM library (libfglrxdrm.so).
[    49.701] (II) LoadModule: "s3"
[    49.701] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/s3_drv.so
[    49.702] (II) Module s3: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.702]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.6.3
[    49.702]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.702]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.702] (II) LoadModule: "tdfx"
[    49.702] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/tdfx_drv.so
[    49.703] (II) Module tdfx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.703]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.4.3
[    49.703]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.703]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.703] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    49.703] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    49.704] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.704]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 0.4.2
[    49.704]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.704] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    49.704] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    49.704] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.704]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 2.3.0
[    49.704]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    49.704]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.704] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for apm
[    49.704] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for neomagic
[    49.704] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for s3virge
[    49.704] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for cirrus
[    49.704] (II) Loading sub module "cirrus_laguna"
[    49.704] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus_laguna"
[    49.704] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_laguna.so
[    49.705] (II) Module cirrus_laguna: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.705]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.0.0
[    49.705]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.705] (II) Loading sub module "cirrus_alpine"
[    49.705] (II) LoadModule: "cirrus_alpine"
[    49.705] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/cirrus_alpine.so
[    49.705] (II) Module cirrus_alpine: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.705]     compiled for 1.8.99.905, module version = 1.0.0
[    49.705]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for ark
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for tseng
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for voodoo
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for trident
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for i128
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for siliconmotion
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for sis
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for sisusb
[    49.705] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    49.740] (II) PCS database file /etc/ati/amdpcsdb not found
[    49.740] (II)   Creating PCS database from initial defaults instead
[    49.740] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for s3
[    49.740] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    49.740] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    49.893] (++) Using config file: "/xorg.conf.new"
[    49.893] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    49.893] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[    49.893] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    49.893] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    49.893] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[    49.893] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    49.893] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    49.893] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    49.894] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    49.894] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    49.894]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.894] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    49.894]     Entry deleted from font path.
[    49.894] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[    49.894] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    49.894] (WW) AllowEmptyInput is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    49.894] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    49.894] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    49.894] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    49.894] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    49.894] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    49.902] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    49.902]     compiled for 1.9.0, module version = 0.0.2
[    49.902]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 8.0
[    49.902] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    49.902] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    49.902] 
Backtrace:
[    49.902] 0: Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x28) [0x4a0fa8]
[    49.902] 1: Xorg (0x400000+0x60fcd) [0x460fcd]
[    49.902] 2: /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f16ba4b6000+0xfb40) [0x7f16ba4c5b40]
[    49.902] Segmentation fault at address (nil)
[    49.902] 
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    49.902] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    49.902] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.99.log" for additional information.
[    49.902]
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You have a ATI Radeon HD 6xxx-Card? After checking [ati's drivers website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) i guess it's not supported at all at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

FGLRX **doesn't work** with switchable graphics yet. In your case, your computer has 2 GPUs, one integrated from intel core processor and a dedicated one from ATI. Since kernel 2.6.35 you can switch between GPUs but JUST using the opensource drivers. Ubuntu Control Center has a nice GUI for this operation.

[image]

Comment: First time I hear about this, can you please supply more information - I'm curies how this thing works. You mean my CPU has a GPU inside of it?

Comment: Yes, all intel core i3,i5 and i7 has an integrated GPU inside it. http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/3084/intel_32nm_clarkdale_core_i5_661_cpu_with_integrated_gpu/index.html